# Weird thing happening while using DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow[] dr;
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Rows.Add(1, 1);
dt.Rows.Add(2, 2);
dt.Rows.Add(3, 3);
dr = dt.Select();
dr[1].Delete();
foreach (DataRow x in dt.Rows)
MessageBox.Show(x[0] + "   " + x[1]);
```

The MessageBox shows me "1   1" and "3   3". Why is this happening? I didn't manipulate the DataTable, just the DataRow[] that holds the values of the DataTable. So why did the values in the DataTable changed also? Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a reference to the selected rows in dr, they are not a copy.  If you delete one then it is gone from dt.rows and dr.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx

You need to call AcceptChanges after the delete:

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: So I use AcceptChanges so that the DataTable will change back to its original values... Thanks :)

Comment: @Gerald, no AcceptChanges will not do that, this answer is not really applicable to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`dr` actually references the rows within the `DataTable dt`. That's why it was deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I thought the values were copied into the DataRow[].